# Size Classes in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

In my iOS 8 app, I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which is defined in a .xib file using autolayout.  I have set up the `UITableView` so that it uses self-sizing cells, and that is all working just fine.

In the .xib file for my cell, I have a design for the "Any x Any" size class, which works. I also wanted a different design for the "Compact x Any" size class, so I added that layout to my .xib.

When I run the app on an iPhone device (real or simulator) I find that the cell is always sized as if it's using my "Any x Any" layout, and yet the content of the cell is always laid out as if it's using my "Compact x Any" size class.  This happens regardless of orientation.

On an iPad device (real or simulator) it always uses the "Any x Any" layout for sizing and layout, which I think is correct.

Has anybody else tried this and got it to work on an iPhone?  It doesn't feel like what I'm trying to do should be an unusual requirement.

In summary, I think the layout is happening correctly on all devices, but the self-sizing cell logic appears not to respect the size class it's in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is a known bug, described here: [rdar://17799811](http://openradar.appspot.com/17799811).

The workaround there is to call `tableView.reloadData()` in my view controller's `viewDidAppear` method.  It does work, but there's an ugly redraw where you see the squashed view content momentarily before it is repainted at the correct size.

In addition, on an iPhone 6 Plus, the vertical size class changes from compact to regular when you change orientation from portrait to landscape, so I also need to redraw when this happens.  I could probably catch the orientation change, but instead (and I think this is the more "correct" approach) I chose to override the newer `traitCollectionDidChange` method in my view controller.  I simply call `tableView.reloadData()` in there.  In this case the change happens quite smoothly and I'm happy with it.  It's just the initial ugly redraw when the table view is first shown that irks me.

Update: I found that relaxing the priority of one of my vertical constraints to 999 made the repaint considerably less ugly.  The cell still changes its height quite noticeably, but at least the contents do not change size.

Comment: I don't know if the problem I saw is the same one you're talking about; I saw the layout not being correct until I scrolled the table or rotated to landscape and then back again (I only saw this with IB created cells, not code created ones). What fixed it for me was to call layoutIfNeeded in an override of the cell's didMoveToSuperview method.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for your comment.  It didn't fix my problem but was worth a try :-)

Comment: I call `tableView.layoutIfNeeded` in `viewWillAppear`. You can also force a redraw by calling `tableView.setNeedsLayout` first.